# Using zxcvbn.js in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am currently trying to use the password strength library zxcvbn.js in QML, without success.

I have the following setup with QT 5.3 and 
the library from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/zxcvbn.js).

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import "zxcvbn.js" as Zxcvbn

ApplicationWindow {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var result =  Zxcvbn.zxcvbn('asdf1234', null);
    }
}
```

Which gives me the following error message:

`TypeError: Property 'zxcvbn' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Has someone already succeeded in using this lib in qml?

Comment: I think the problem is the self executing function around at the script. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Most JS libraries are not ready to use in QML "as is", because they adopted for browser usage. Try to find entry point of the library and wrap it with top-level js function in *.js file. I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation of the library:

> zxcvbn is designed for node and the browser

By looking at the code, I found that it finally acts either on the `window` or the `exports` object, if at least one of them exists.

Because of that, I guess you won't be able to use it unless you modify it. Maybe it's worth trying some tricky approach that directly pushes the required objects in the global space, so that they happen to be reachable, but I'm not sure it's a viable solution or, at least, a suitable one.